# In linguistics, what is called when you use a word to down-play something?

Tags: terminology, semantics, pragmatics

In any theories of semantics or pragmatics such as Grice’s Maxims and Speech Act Theory, is there a term when you use a word to “down-play”, “mitigate”, “soften-the-blow” of a word?

I concoct a few examples to illustrate what I mean:

> It’s not *that* bad!
>
> I will only *just* be gone for a few months!

I’m sure there are much more examples, but those are the only ones I could think of to mind.

The terms/phrase that come to mind of what it could be are: “intensifier”, “filler” and “mitigation” [*] but I’m not sure if these are appropriate

[*] There is “Mitigtion theory” (mitigate: to make something appear less severe) but I do not know enough about it or whether it’s a linguistic or grammatical theory.

Comment: The _Cambridge Dictionary_ (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hedges-just) includes _just_ as an example of _hedging_. Hedging is not exactly the term you seem to be looking for, but there appears to be somewhat (another hedge!) of an overlap. See also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)

Comment: This Q really belongs on [linguistics.se] where it has already been dealt with in this post: "Opposite of “intensifier”? " https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9974

Comment: And the correct term is here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/downtoners

Comment: @Shoe Yes, as you suspected, "hedge" is **not** quite the same as "downtoner."